# appending text in a jTextBox

Tags: java, jtextarea

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {// handle button event

        Object source = evt.getSource();
        String k = evt.getActionCommand();
        jTextArea1.append(k);
    }
```

i have the code above and an error at `jTextArea1.append(k);`. The error am getting is

> cannot find symbol   symbol:   method
>   append(java.lang.String)   location:
>   variable txtArea of type
>   javax.swing.JTextField

if i use jTextArea1.settext(k); , it works but i want to append text the existing

Comment: Are you sure you are using JTextArea because error tells that you are using JTextField? ---- *cannot find symbol symbol: method append(java.lang.String) location: variable **txtArea of type javax.swing.JTextField***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the error message, the `jTextArea1` is actually a [`JTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html).

Try

```
jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText() + k);
```

Answer (score 1):

Seem like the type of `jTextArea1` is `JTextField`. Declare jTextArea1 as

```
JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
```

Then you will be able to use the method `append("string")`.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use :

```
String x = jTextArea.getText();
String a = x + k ;    // String k = evt.getActionCommand();
jTextArea.setText(a);
```